# Solidity Mapping use string to find struct?

Tags: solidity

I want to use the mapping find the struct but the mapping just can use the bytes and I need to use the string.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract land{

    address public owner;

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Landpaper{
        string number;
        string landaddress;
        string landnumber;
        string landpurpose;
        uint landgrades;
        uint256 landarea;
        string holdpoints;
    }

    mapping(bytes8 => Landpaper) public lp;

    modifier Permission(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function set(string memory rfidnumber, Landpaper memory _landpaperRecord) public Permission{
        lp[rfidnumber]=_landpaperRecord;
    }

    function get(string memory rfidnumber) view public returns(Landpaper memory){
        return lp[rfidnumber];
    }

}
```

because I have to read the rfid UID and I will translate the UID to string, so I need to use the string set my data. I use the bytes8 and I input string type, I need to change my string to bytes8, plz told me how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to convert string to bytes8

```
function stringToBytes8(string memory sourceStr) private pure returns(bytes8) {
    bytes8 temp = 0x0;
    assembly {
        temp := mload(add(sourceStr, 32))
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And call it from `set` and `get` functions

```
function set(string memory rfidnumber, Landpaper memory _landpaperRecord) public Permission {
    bytes8 rfidb8 = stringToByte8(rfidnumber);
    lp[rfidb8]=_landpaperRecord;
}

function get(string memory rfidnumber) public view returns(Landpaper memory) {
    bytes8 rfidb8 = stringToByte8(rfidnumber);
    return lp[rfidb8];
}
```

Though I would suggest to avoid performing conversion process in `contract` as it would consume unnecessary `gas`. Instead perform the conversion on client side and pass `bytes8` as parameter

```
function set(bytes8 rfidnumber, Landpaper memory _landpaperRecord) public Permission {
    lp[rfidnumber]=_landpaperRecord;
}

function get(bytes8 rfidnumber) public view returns(Landpaper memory) {
    return lp[rfidnumber];
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's really good, and I found another function can solve my question, I change the mapping
"mapping(bytes8 => Landpaper) public lp" to "mapping(string=> Landpaper) lp".
It can work but I don't know what risk in this?

Comment: Generally `string` requires more `gas` than `bytes` when performing operations.

Comment: OK I see, i want to give you a useful but I'm not enough reputation, sorry.